# WordPress Theme Cross-Compatability with Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on a Theme for a client which looks fine in FireFox, however in Internet Explorer it looks completely messed up. The link to the site is http://www.freesamplesnetwork.com/. If anyone has any advice, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have some code errors, primarily a comment

`<!-- Calls header.php to display header -->`

above the doctype in header.php which throws IE into quirks mode.

Fix that and then revalidate: [[Invalid] Markup Validation of   freesamplesnetwork.com  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//www.freesamplesnetwork.com/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.

Comment: I just removed that. Any idea which error is actually causing it?

Comment: Start fixing them all, esp. the missing closing tags and the out of place head and body tags.